# Reveal user@hostname in oh-my-fish theme

Tags: shell, shell-script, fish

I'm trying to have the user@hostname displayed all the time in fish's [bobthefish](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish/blob/master/docs/Themes.md#bobthefish) theme, no matter whether you're the default user or not. I've tried editing `~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish`, which has the following section:

```
function __bobthefish_prompt_user -S -d 'Display actual user if different from $default_user'
  if [ "$theme_display_user" = 'yes' ]
    if [ "$USER" != "$default_user" -o -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]
      __bobthefish_start_segment $__color_username
      set -l IFS .
      hostname | read -l hostname __
      echo -ns (whoami) '@' $hostname ' '
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried removing lines 3 and 8 then restarting the terminal to no avail. It seems that simple on first sight, but then again, I don't really understand `-o -n "$SSH_CLIENT"` either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`-o -n "$SSH_CLIENT"` means: or (`-o`) the variable $SSH_CLIENT contains a string (`-n "$SSH_CLIENT"`)

`$SSH_CLIENT` is set if you are logged in via SSH. So the user@hostname will always be displayed if you are logged in remotely.